# Using Google AppEngine Namespace but be able to access all tenants data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking into different ways to implement multi tenant application - one of which is using AppEngine namespace API.

One of the requirements is that we will be able to access data of different tenants, but each tenant can access only it own data. This way we will be able to see trends that happen over several tenants.

Is it possible to do such thing using AppEngine namespace API ?

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do that, partly, by using the `NamespaceManager.set` method to access specific tenant data.
I can select one tenant data at a time but that's fine by me.

Ido.

Answer (score 2):

Administrative access, where admins have access over all namespaces, but non-admin tenants have access to only their own, is something that is easily implemented using a small number of methods from the Namespaces and Users services.

See
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/overview

Comment: thank you. It means I have to write it myself and also means I will not be able to query across tenants. At least not easily, right?

Comment: Correct, a query is always limited to a namespace.